# listof (float package) mixes many differents floats (memoir)

Tags: floats

As said, I have a problem when I create new float type with float.

My preamble contains

```
\newfloat{protocol}{tHp}{lop}
\floatname{protocol}{Protocole}
\newfloat{fonction}{tHp}{lop}
\floatname{fonction}{Fonctionnalité}
```

Now, my document contains some protocols, and some "fonctions". But when I use the `\listof` command, a strange thing happens.

If I use `\listof{fonction}{Liste des fonctionnalités}`, it will look like this:

[image]

Same thing happens if I use  `\listof{protocol}{Liste des protocoles}`.

I have no idea where to look at to correct that :/

```
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,caption,color,amsthm,complexity,mathtools,float,enumitem,color,lettrine,pdfpages,hyperref,mathspec,framed,tocloft}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill My bad, I'll provide a MWE next time.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified `lop` as the file extension for storing the respective listings for *both* `protocol` and `fonction`.  `\listof` is not smart enough to recognize and ignore entries for the wrong type of table, so you need to specify different file extensions in your `\newfloat` commands.

Comment: @znieh: If this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764). This is done separate from up-voting.

Comment: Actually, "is not smart enough" is a euphemism.  If the intent was *not* to have mixed files, there would have been no point writing different commands for different float types to the file.  *Obviously* the "other" commands should be ignored including their arguments.  The way to do that is have `\newfloat` define the respective listing command to just discard its arguments, and then have `\listof` enable just the right command *locally* (currently it is done globally).  About 5 changed lines, and stuff would work as expected without needing a separate file for each float type.